# How to load the correct image from my database to the correct item when I click on my pin?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, maps

So I have a map in my code with multiple pins. When I click on a pin I get to a newpage with the pintitle. That works but If I want to add an image/and or description to that same page (that I also store on my database, parse) it doesnt work as I only get the topimage stored in the database on every different pin i click.

```
string picture;
string theDescription;

var getItems = await parseAPI.getInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString ()); //I load my data.

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) 
{

var prodPic = "";
if(currentItem["image"] != null)
{
    prodPic = (string)currentItem ["image"] ["url"];
}
picture = prodPic; //i add the picture.
theDescription = currentItem ["description"].ToString (); // i add the descrption
dName = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); //and the title

    var pin = new Pin ();
    pin.Position = new Position (16,13);
    pin.Label = dName; //and then i connect my title here so it works, but how should I do it with my picture + description?
    pin.Address = "click for info";
    pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;

    theMap.Pins.Add (pin); //adding my pins to my map. 
  }

void onButtonClicked1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pin pin = (Pin)sender;

        Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailPage (pin.Label, picture, theDescription )); //label works, so every pin get a unique label, but picture + the description remains the same inside the item i enter.

    }
```

so It works with the title, and that is because I have connected the pin to my onbuttonclicked1 (pin.label) function I assume? so I how should I do it with my image + description so the pin does not get the same picture + description on every pin i enter

UPDATED IDEA:

```
new List <String> ourItems = new List<String> ();

ourItems.Add (theDescription);
ourItems.Add (picture);
```

Like this? and then somehow connect them into my OnButtonClicked1 function?

Answer (score 1):

You are running a foreach loop which repeatedly sets the same "picture" variable. That is, every time you iterate, you are setting the "picture" and "description" variables to whatever value is relevant for the current iteration without actually persisting any of the previous values anywhere.

Your loop would look something like this:

> Iteration one: picture = "pictureOne.png";
>
> Iteration two: picture = "pictureTwo.png";
>
> Iteration three: picture = "PictureThree.png";
>
> ...etc

What this means is that by the time your loop ends, you will have reset your imagine multiple times, with the variable retaining its last set value (in the above example that would be "pictureThree.png"

One way (not necessarily the best, mind you) would be to have an empty list, which you then populate from within the loop.

Comment: Hmm ok. Kinda understand what you mean but not quite sure how to execute the code.

Comment: I have put a update on the code now (below the previous code), am i heading the right direction?

Comment: Not quite - you'll want an intermediary class in there that's there purely to store your data in the structure you want. If I manage to stay awake, I'll post an example in a few hours (working, currently) in case it's still needed

Comment: That would be very helpful! I will let you know here if I am able to solve it before you end work.

Comment: @DiddanDo Apologies, got overwhelmed with things. Will try and get you a proper response tonight, if still needed (GMT time) :)